# Damaged path importing from PDF to Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pdf, path, import

I imported a logo from PDF to Illustrator 21.0.0 and I get this unusual result. The path is fine and smooth when viewed in keyline mode (the second picture) while the rendered version (first picture) is fragmented and it has some weird glitches (like that pink thing on the top right) that are not there in the path-only view.

How to fix this?

[image: how it looks]
[image: path]

Answer (score 2):

Solved.

It was a glitch in the GPU preview, as suggested by Joonas I just had to select: `View > Preview on CPU`.

Thanks.

Comment: If your own answer is the best answer (or in this case, the only one), please mark it as 'accepted'. This is good for site stats and also tells later visitors that this was actually the correct solution. Thanks!